# Is there any row limit for excel using BIFF?

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, biff

I have a code to export my data grid to excell using BIFF4. The problem is it cant accept rows beyond 65536. I asuume it is because the row index is word and it is of 2 bytes. Is there any way i could write more than the available row count? any workaround is possible? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: no. you can't. other than using multiple worksheets, you cannot break a fundamental limit in excel. it'd be like asking how to represent `8 billion` in a 32bit var. If you upgrade to the OOXML format (.xlsx), you can use up to 1 million rows.

Comment: Using an output format like CSV seems like an obvious workaround

Comment: @MarcB: Assume if upgrade to BIFF5 or anything greater than that will i be able to export more rows?

Comment: No. the biff formats all have basically the same limits. 64k max for biff5/biff8. for 1million rows, you need the xml-based version from 2007+ (.xlsx).

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use BIFF, the best thing to do is split the data into multiple sheets.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 97-2003, the row limit is 65535 per sheet. It should be the default BIFF row limit.